# Test if samples are paired

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have two samples without further information. In order to apply a t-test I want to know if they are paired. Is there a test in R that allows you to check if two samples are paired?

Comment: R does not know if you measured ben's blood pressure twice or ben's and his brother jimmy's blood pressure once.

Answer (score 3):

R cannot possibly check whether the samples are paired as this requires qualitative information about the sample. You need to know whether the data of those two samples are from the same individuals / whatever is examined here.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to know this in R. at max, you can check their correlation, and if they are highly correlated, this gives you a tiny bit of idea that they might be paired. However, this is not a conclusive test for paired sample.

Two samples can be called pairs because of several different reasons.

Examples of paired samples include:
• pre-test/post-test samples in which a factor is measured before and after an
intervention,
• cross-over trials in which individuals are randomized to two treatments and then the
same individuals are crossed-over to the alternative treatment,
• matched samples, in which individuals are matched on personal characteristics such as
age and sex,
• duplicate measurements on the same biological samples, and
• any circumstance in which each data point in one sample is uniquely matched to a data
point in the second sample.

Anything opposite of this would be independent samples. ***So the identification of paired samples depends on your knowledge of data.***